# Error at my logo beside the text

Tags: html

I'm currently learning basic html. What's wrong with my code, why the logo is appearing on the right side of the text but I already assigned it on the left side.

```html
<html>

<title>Registration Form</title>

<center>
    <h3>
        <font color="336699">
            Asia Pacific College
            <img src="Asia_Pacific_College_Logo.png" style="width:32px;height:32px;" vertical- align="left">
        </font>
    <h3>
    <h4>
        <font color="336699">Office of the Registrar</font>
    <h4>
</center>
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: There is a space `vertical- align`. It should be `vertical-align`

Comment: Whatever you're reading to learn HTML, please burn it right now and look for something else. `<font>` has been dead for more than a decade now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: First: the `vertical- align` is obviously wrong (typo), then it must be inside the style attribute (there is not html attribute of such name). `style="width:32px;height:32px;vertical-align:left;"`. Next: vertical alignment with a "left" value does not make any sense, only top, bottom or middle are defined. Further: style your font by css means too, not using a html `<font>` element and a `<center>` element does work, but is questionable. Use a centered or full width `<div>` instead..  Last: use css files instead of inline-styling.

Comment: Please, learn HTML with an updated manual. This `center` and `font` tags are the devil in web development

Answer (score 0):

First typo mistake.
Second, you might be trying to make it Horizontally in left side not Vertically.

And the image/logo show right side of the text as you placed the img tag after the text "Asia Pacific College". If you put the img tag before, you'll see the img at left side.

Or Apply the below css to change the alignment of the image --

```
  h4 img {
     float: left; // or right if you want to put it right side of the text. 
  }
```